# passing $event to unit test case mocha

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I have a method `init` my `controller` like below, how can i test this:

```
vm.init = function ($event) {
  var target = angular.element($event.target);
  if(target.prop('tagName').toUpperCase() == 'A') {
    return false;
  }
};
```

TestSpec

```
beforeEach(function(){

   vm.init = sinon.spy();
   compiled = $compile(template)($scope);

   $scope.$digest();   

   mockEvent = new Event('click');
   sinon.spy(mockEvent, 'preventDefault');
});

it('init() method should return false', function() {
    vm.init(mockEvent);      
});

TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

How can i pass the `$event` here, below is my html where the event is triggered.

```
template = '<div id="fre"><span ng-click="init($event)"></span></div>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock the `$event` creating an object with a target property set to any HTML string.

```
it('init() method should return false', function() {
  var mockEvent = {
    target: '<a href="#">Click</a>'
  };
  expect(controller.init(mockEvent)).toBe(false)
});
```

Comment: What if i want to check for $event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: You can add a `preventDefault` property being a function or a spy.